# Displaying Big Maps in RViz

Tags: navigation, mapping, rviz, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a large map that I'm trying to display in RViz.  However, it appears highly downsampled. The debugging is shown here:

```
[DEBUG] [1445440488.123087442]: Received a 10032 X 6075 map @ 0.020 m/pix
[ WARN] [1445440488.187623157]: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Zero sized texture surface on texture MapTexture1 face 0 mipmap 0. Probably, the GL driver refused to create the texture. in GLTexture::_createSurfaceList at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLTexture.cpp (line 420)
[ WARN] [1445440488.188283064]: Failed to create full-size map texture, likely because your graphics card does not support textures of size > 2048.  Downsampling to [2048 x 1240]...
```

Is there any way to get around this restriction?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219614/displaying-big-maps-in-rviz/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2015-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Fixed here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/pull/1007)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2017-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0